# How to get mempool pending transactions using web3.py and Chainstack websocket

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

How to subscribe to chainstack node websocket to receive mempool pending transactions using web3.py

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider('wss://ws-nd-732-321-545.p2pify.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXX'))
print(w3.eth.blockNumber)
subscription = w3.eth.filter('pending')
```

need rest of the code

Answer (score -1):

I'm with Chainstack. For anyone looking for this, we have the working instructions in our knowledge base: [Subscribing to global new pending transactions with web3.js](https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/900003426246-Subscribing-to-global-new-pending-transactions-with-web3-js).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33005865)